# Displaying data on JSP containing varying length <td>

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

I need help in displaying data on JSP in a particular format. 
The data for the JSP is coming from java code in the form of a list which inturn is taking data from beans, basically I have a list of beans on my JSP page.
My data needs to be in a particular format, similar to the below table:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<body>
<table border="1">
   
 <!-- Below row is supposed to be the linking element, lets call it Dep#  -->
<tr>
 <th>22603</th>
 <th>23926</th>
 <th>25018</th>
 <th>26441</th>
 <th>29757</th>
 <th>31798</th>
 <th>32436</th>
 <th>32699</th>
 <th>37948</th>
</tr>

<tr> <!-- Below set of row's are supposed to be the linked element, lets call it Emp# -->
 <td>41162</td>
 <td>37362</td>
 <td>38311</td>
 <td>37773</td>
 <td>38666</td>
 <td>40056</td>
 <td>37519</td>
 <td>38389</td>
 <td>37596</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td></td>
 <td>38824</td>
 <td>38896</td>
 <td></td>
 <td>39498</td>
 <td></td>
 <td>37548</td>
 <td></td>
 <td>37442</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td></td>
 <td></td>
 <td>41009</td>
 <td></td>
 <td>37827</td>
 <td></td>
 <td></td>
 <td></td>
 <td>37259</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td></td>
 <td></td>
 <td>41180</td>
 <td></td>
 <td>37473</td>
 <td></td>
 <td></td>
 <td></td>
 <td>37537</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td></td>
 <td></td>
 <td>41967</td>
 <td></td>
 <td>37856</td>
 <td></td>
 <td></td>
 <td></td>
 <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td></td>
 <td></td>
 <td>38805</td>
 <td></td>
 <td>39307</td>
 <td></td>
 <td></td>
 <td></td>
 <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td></td>
 <td></td>
 <td>40690</td>
 <td></td>
 <td>40176</td>
 <td></td>
 <td></td>
 <td></td>
 <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td></td>
 <td></td>
 <td>42144</td>
 <td></td>
 <td>38667</td>
 <td></td>
 <td></td>
 <td></td>
 <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td></td>
 <td></td>
 <td></td>
 <td></td>
 <td>38390</td>
 <td></td>
 <td></td>
 <td></td>
 <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td></td>
 <td></td>
 <td></td>
 <td></td>
 <td>37845</td>
 <td></td>
 <td></td>
 <td></td>
 <td></td>
</tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

The list which is being passed from backend code has the following 2 beans in it:
 1. deptNum(1 Dept can have many Emp)
 2. empNum(1 Emp can be part of only 1 Dept)

How can I achieve this particular format of data for display?

Comment: You should show us the exact "list which is being passed from backend".

Comment: Below is the pseudo code on how my list is getting generated at backend:
`code`
myFunction(){
execute SQL query
while(rslt.next()){
deptBean.setDeptNum(rslt.getInt(1));
deptBean.setEmpNum(rslt.getInt(2));
myList.add(deptBean);
}
return myList
}
`code`
In my servlet, I pass the list to JSP using request.setAttribute("myList",myList)

Answer (score 0):

`<td></td>` should be `<td>&nbsp;</td>` because when there's nothing inside the `<td></td>` the browser typically just kind of doesn't display it. `&nbsp;` is a non-breaking space.

Answer (score 0):

According to your question, basically you have a set of Departments and many list of employees which belong to these departments.

I suggest you to solve this with "java.util.Set" and "java.util.Map".

In sense of "each employee has only one Department" means we have a list of Departments and they are unique in this list. So use "Set" instead of "List" passing from the backend.

Secondly, you can use this set as a KeySet of each employee Map. Then each  map can show each department's employee if it exists for this map.

Finally, you can prepare a list of map to traverse in JSP part.

```
Set<String> deptSet = ....

foreach (String deptNum : deptSet) {
  print("<th>" + deptNum + "</th>");
}

...

List<Map<String,String>> empMapList = ....

foreach (empMap : empMapList) {
  Set empSet = empMap.getValues();

  foreach (String empNum : empSet) {
    if (empNum == null) 
      print("<td>&nbsp;/td>");
    else 
      print("<td>" + empNum + "</td>");
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks @Afsin for your suggestion, even I was thinking whether I should be using Map in this scenario as list doesnt seems to be the best way out.